# Apparent counterexamples to claims of tautologies in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

I'm reading the paper "A fixpoint semantics and an SLD-resolution calculus for modal logic programs" by L.A.Nguyen, and in the paper he asserts that certain tautologies hold, but it seems that there are counter-examples. Am I missing something, or is the paper just incorrect?

We have the logic KD5 which is a standard modal logic with additional axiom schemata (D): $\square\phi\rightarrow\phi$ and (5): $\diamond\phi\rightarrow\square\diamond\phi$. Let $\nabla$ below indicate any modal operator, $\square$ or $\diamond$.

Then in the paper it is claimed that $\nabla\nabla_1 \nabla_2\phi = \nabla_1\nabla_2\phi$.  However, it seems we can construct a Kripke model satisfying KD5 but violating this claim:
define worlds $w_0$,$w_1$,$w_2$,$w_3$ with accessibility relation given by $w_0\to w_1\to w_2\to w_3\to w_3$. This is a "serial" relation (every world has a reachable neighbor), so it satisfies (D). And since every world has a unique reachable neighbor, it (trivially) is a "Euclidean" relation, so it satisfies (5).  This also implies that $w_0\models\square\phi\equiv\diamond\phi$ for any $\phi$, hence $w_0\models\nabla\neg\phi\equiv\neg\nabla\phi$.  Now let $w_3\models\phi$ and $w_2\models\neg\phi$.  Then $w_0\models\diamond\diamond\neg\phi$, hence $w_0\models\neg\diamond\diamond\phi$, but also $w_0\models\diamond\diamond\diamond\phi$.  But this contradicts the claimed general relation.

There is a similar claim in the paper that $\diamond\nabla\phi\equiv\square\nabla\phi$ in KD5 with another apparent counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed counterexample does not satisfy $(5)$. Consider the valuation making $p$ true at $w_1$ and false everywhere else. Then at $w_0$, $\Diamond p$ is true but $\Box\Diamond p$ is false.

Relatedly, your claim of Euclideanness is incorrect, the issue being that the accessibility relation in your proposed counterexample is not reflexive.

Comment: The reflexivity may be the element I was missing - but I haven't noticed that as part of the definition of KD5 (it relates to T, i.e. $\square\phi\rightarrow\phi$).  Is that assumed as part of the logics or implied somehow?

Comment: @Apollo My point is that your claim that "each world sees a unique world" implies Euclideanness is wrong: Euclideanness is the property $$xRy\wedge xRz\implies yRz,$$ and that's not going on here. But the more substantive part is just that your proposed counterexample doesn't validate (5) per the first part of my answer.

Comment: And, yes, as you point out, my model does not satisfy the axiom schema (5) for _all_ formula.  (For example, with my same valuation is that at $w_0$ we have $\diamond\diamond\neg\phi$ but $\neg\square\diamond\diamond\neg\phi$.)

Comment: Oops, yes, of course, $y,z$ don't have to be distinct.  Duh. 

Thanks!  I managed to fit two different confusions into a single question : -)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Axiom 5 directly corresponds to a Euclidean accessibility relation.

Comment: @PW_246 Yes, so? (The point of my answer is that the OP's idea does not actually satisfy $(5)$ since it's not Eucldiean after all.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber My point is that Euclideanness doesn’t require reflexivity. However, the accessibility condition proposed by OP is still vacuously Euclidean since for each world $w$ there is exactly one world $v$ such that $wRv$.

Comment: @PW_246 No, Euclideanness doesn't require full reflexivity, but it does require that every seen world is reflexive: if $wRv$ then we have $wRv\wedge wRv$ so by Euclideanness $vRv$. This is relevant to the OP's setup.

Comment: That makes sense.